# Running Javascript Code Used to Run on NodeJS

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I have a code that is running on NodeJs. We would like to change the technology (to java).
The problem is we have some existing passwords, and I am not sure how to I copy the encryption logic to java.
So, one of the possible solutions is to run the encryption logic in javascript (e.g. command line, embbeded in the java, etc) and get the result back.

The question is - how do I do that?

The nodejs code goes like this:

```
crypto = require('crypto');
this.salt = this.makeSalt();

encryptPassword: function(password) {
   var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
   return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, keylen).toString('base64');
   crypto.randomBytes(..)
}

makeSalt: function() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(numOfBytes).toString('base64');
},
```

UPDATE:
Following the suggestions here, I added the full code. If the right way of doing it is by transforming the javascript code to java code, can you please help me translated the above code?

Comment: Don't. If you do not know how to port language specific functions to Java, you can ask us.

Comment: the @alandarev, I added the full code. can you please help me transform it to java?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with crypto module.. But there are more people than just me on this site. It might be wise to leave this questino as it was, accept the answer, and create new question, so that it gets back into 'new questions' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this, if you want random bytes in Java do this. You should be able to replicate the encryption logic in Java.

```
byte[] b = new byte[20];
new Random().nextBytes(b);
```

Almost all of the Node.js crypto functions are generic, and should have their own Java counterparts or 3rd party libraries.

**Update**

If you must run your node code via java you can add this method

```
public static String runCommand(String command) {
    String output = "";

    try {
        String line;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()) );
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line;
        }
        reader.close();


    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // ...
    }

    return output;
}
```

and run it like this

```
    String encryptedPassword = runCommand("node myEncryption.js --password=1234");
```

Comment: thx chad. I didn't bring the whole code, for simplicity. so I edited the qeustion.
can you please help me transform the code to javacode?